# property inaccessible due to protection level?

Tags: c#

This is the line that the error is showing on:

```
public IOAuth2ServiceProvider<IElance> ElanceServiceProvider { get; set; }
```

It's showing the error on the `IElance` Type on that line, but here's the interface:

```
public interface IElance : IApiBinding
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Search all jobs, list jobs associated with an employee or a freelancer, and retrieve information for a specific job.
        /// </summary>
        IJobOperations JobOperations { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Access all messages, users, messages, and Work View™ data associated with an Elance Workroom.
        /// </summary>
        IWorkRoomOperations WorkroomOperations { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// View all of the information associated with an employee or a freelancer.
        /// </summary>
        IProfileOperations ProfileOperations { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// View detailed information on freelancers, and retrieve a list of all freelancers employed by an employer.
        /// </summary>
        IFreelancerOperations FreelancerOperations { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// List Elance groups, and retrieve lists of members and jobs belonging to a group.
        /// </summary>
        IGroupOperations GroupOperations { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtain ancillary Elance information, such as the current list of all job categories.
        /// </summary>
        IUtilityOperations UtilityOperations { get; }
    }
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why it's telling me this. Am I missing something obvious? I would greatly appreciate any direction on this error.

Comment: IApiBinding's accessibility status is?

Comment: Update with body of interface

Comment: updated with body of interface

Comment: Do you get the same error if you just declare a public member variable of type 'IElance'? i.e. 

public IElance temp;

Comment: what's the complete error?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by `IApiBinding` or one of its base interfaces not being `public`. Another possibility is that one of the types used by the interface members is not public.

Comment: How would i find that out? its in an external library

Comment: In that case it's more likely it's one of the types of the interface members. Are they all public?

Comment: it won't let me use the `public` modifier in an interface

Comment: I'm not talking about the interface members, but the *types* of the members. Are the interfaces `IJobOperations`, `IWorkRoomOperations`, etc. declared public?

Comment: This happened to me because I had my interface marked as class instead of interface.  I'm so stupid.